# Buying tokens with OpenZepplin crowdsale

Tags: solidity, tokens, crowdsale, openzeppelin

I am running into a very strange bug while interacting with my OpenZepplin crowdsale.

Here is my repo for context https://github.com/GenusDev/crossfit-coin-backend

Here is what I have working so far:

1. Deploy a Crowdsale contract: success
2. Deploy a MintableToken: success
3. Transfer ownership of MintableToken to Crowdsale: success
4. Attempt to buyTokens from front-end app (line 76 of app.js):
   FAIL...but then,if I run the same buyTokens command once through the Truffle
   CLI, I can then refresh the page of my front-end app and run the
   exact same code (line 76 of app.js) and successfully buyTokens.

Its not a timing issue. I have waited several minutes after deployment, and step 4 works from the front-end immediately after running the same command through the CLI. Can anyone offer advice here?

Comment: Are you testing against ganache, geth or parity? Does buyTokens fails with any error message?

Comment: I am testing on Ganache. The error I get is: "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"

Answer (score 1):

The error is: The buyTokens() call did not specify the gas limit.
Original function call:

`buyTokens(<<0xaccountAddress>>, { from: <<0xaccountAddress>>, value: web3.toWei(5, "ether") })`

should be:

`buyTokens(0xaccountAddress>>, { from: <<0xaccountAddress>>, value: web3.toWei(5, "ether"), gas: '1000000' })`